# data.frame filtering function too slow

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I am trying to filter a data frame of mine, with about 200 thousand rows, using R.
The dataframe is structured as follow:

```
testdf<- data.frame("CHROM"='CHR8', "POS"=c(500,510), "ID"='Some_value',
                        "REF"=c('A','C'), "ALT"=c('C','T,G'), "Some_more_stuff"='More_info')
```

I am trying to filter the rows based on how many letters are in the 'ALT' column, being equal to or lesser than a custom threshold. In the example above, if my threshold is 1, only the first row would be retained (the second row - ALT column- has 2 letters > 1).

I have written a couple of functions, which do the job. The only problem is that they take several seconds on a test dataframe with just 14 rows. On the real dataframe (200,000 rows) it takes forever. I am looking for advice on how writing better syntax and get faster results.
Here are my functions:

```
# Function no. 1:
allele_number_filtering<- function (snp_table, max_alleles=1, ALT_column=5) {
  #here I calculate how many letters are in the ALT column
  alt_allele_list_length <- function(ALT_field) {
    alt_length<- length(strsplit(as.character
                                 (ALT_field), split = ',')[[1]])
    return(alt_length)}
  # Create an empty dataframe with same columns as the input df
  final_table<- snp_table[0,]
  # Now only retain the rows that are <= max_alleles
  for (i in 1:nrow(snp_table)) {
    if (alt_allele_list_length(snp_table[i, ALT_column]) <= max_alleles) {
      final_table<- rbind(final_table, snp_table[i,])}}
  return(final_table)}

#Function no. 2:
allele_number_filtering<- function (snp_table, max_alleles=1, ALT_column=5) {
  final_table<- snp_table[0,]
  for (i in 1: nrow(snp_table)) {
    if (length(strsplit(as.character(snp_table[i,ALT_column]),
                        split = ',')[[1]])<=max_alleles) {
      final_table<- rbind(final_table, snp_table[i,])
    }}
  return(final_table)}
```

I would be thankful for any advice :)
Max

EDIT: I realized I also had values such as 'ALT' = 'at' (still to be counted as 1) or 'ALT' = 'aa,at' (to be counted as 2 ).

Comment: If you don't mind removing the commas from the ALT column, you could also do this in one line with `nchar`.

Comment: Even without removing the commas it should work. In this case you need to add `(n-1)` to your treshold.

Comment: @sgibb, that would assume that there are two characters maximum

Comment: @docendodiscimus you are partly right, this would assume one-letter-code (as it is for dna bases) divided by commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `lengths()` for this:

```
testdf[lengths(strsplit(as.character(testdf$ALT), ',',fixed = TRUE))<=1,]
```

Thanks @docendodiscimus for `strsplit( fixed=TRUE)` option for speed up and to @joran for his perspicacity

Comment: That's great, thanks! I just tried it and it's very fast! It also works if the comma separates groups of characters, e.g. 'ALT' = 'aa,at' is still counted as 2, which is what I need

Comment: I didn't suggest `fixed = TRUE`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `nchar` for this (before I would remove the `,` via `gsub`):

```
nchar(gsub(",", "", as.character(testdf$ALT)))
# [1] 1 2

threshold <- 1
testdf[nchar(gsub(",", "", as.character(testdf$ALT))) > threshold, ]
#   CHROM POS         ID REF ALT Some_more_stuff
# 2  CHR8 510 Some_value   C T,G       More_info
```

Comment: Thank you, sgibb! Looking back to my dataset, I realized I also had values such as 'ALT' = 'at' (still to be counted as 1) or 'ALT' = 'aa,at' (to be counted as 2 ). That is why I chose Huber's answer. My bad, you both answered before I could edit. thanks again for your help :)